# Centering problem in minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I want to center the quotations with a indent. 
Here is the codes and results:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\centering
“What I like about photographs is that they capture a moment that’s gone forever, impossible to reproduce.”
\\―Karl Lagerfeld
\\“A good snapshot keeps a moment from running away.” 
\\― Eudora Welty
\end{minipage}
\\Photography is the strongest way to keep memories. In today’s world it is really easy....
```

Here is the result:
[image]

And I want to center the quatations according the page size. How can I modify?
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `\\` for new paragraph. Use an empty line instead (or `\par`).

The quotes are put in a minipage of width `0.7\textwidth` where the text is centered. But you also need to center the minipage on the page. (I have also replaced `\textwidth`with `\linewidth`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \centering
    ``What I like about photographs is that they capture a moment that’s gone forever, impossible to reproduce.''

    ---Karl Lagerfeld

    ``A good snapshot keeps a moment from running away.''

    ---Eudora Welty
  \end{minipage}%  
\end{center}
Photography is the strongest way to keep memories. In today’s world it is really easy....
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach: use the `quote` environment instead of a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}
\centering
“What I like about photographs is that they capture a moment that’s gone forever, impossible to reproduce.”

―Karl Lagerfeld

“A good snapshot keeps a moment from running away.” 

― Eudora Welty
\end{quote}

Photography is the strongest way to keep memories. In today’s world it is really easy....

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `quoting` package gives you full control on the homonymous environment. Alternatively, depending on the real context, you might use the `epigraph` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{leftmargin=0.22\linewidth, rightmargin=0.22\linewidth, indentfirst=false}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{0.65\linewidth}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%\lipsum[11]
\begin{quoting}
  “What I like about photographs is that they capture a moment that’s gone forever, impossible to reproduce.”

  \centering―Karl Lagerfeld
\end{quoting}

\begin{quoting}
  “A good snapshot keeps a moment from running away.”

  \centering― Eudora Welty
\end{quoting}
Photography is the strongest way to keep memories. In today’s world it is really easy…
\newpage

\epigraph{“What I like about photographs is that they capture a moment that’s gone forever, impossible to reproduce.”}
{― Karl Lagerfeld}
\epigraph{“A good snapshot keeps a moment from running away.”}
{― Eudora Welty}

Photography is the strongest way to keep memories. In today’s world it is really easy…

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]